# <promise void> in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to learn typescript but i am not clear on few concepts on typescript such as:

1) I am but not the part `Object = Object.assign`

```
export const htmlElementsMap: Object = Object.assign(
  {},
  homePageElementsMap,
  loginPageElementsMap,
  productDetailPageElementsMap,
  productListPageElementsMap,
  shoppingBagPageElementsMap,
  thankYouPageElementsMap
);
```

2) Same with this part `export const UrlNavigationMap: Object = {`
What is an object?

3) For this function i am not sure what does this `PromiseLike<void>` means:

```
performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    return actor.attemptsTo(
      Click.on(homePageElementsMap.lnk_men),
      SearchItemBySku.called()
    );
  }
```

4) `export class FillShippingAddress implements Task {}` - What does implements means?

and last:

5) What is a `static` and why it is assigned to the class name?

```
export class AddItemsToShoppingBag implements Task{
  static called(gender: string): AddItemsToShoppingBag {
    return new AddItemsToShoppingBag(gender);
  }
```

Comment: You have several questions here so you should probably split them up, but a lot of these questions have existing answers. For starters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712705/why-does-typescript-use-like-types

Answer (score 6):

> 1. I am but not the part `const htmlElementsMap: Object`

`:Object` is a type annotation. [Some notes on type annotations](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html)

> 2. What is an `Object`

It is the type of standard JavaScript objects : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Object

> 3. what does this `PromiseLike<void>` means:

`PromiseLike` is something that follows the a+ promise spec : https://promisesaplus.com/

The browser native `Promise` is one implementation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

`<void>` is a [generic type annotation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/generics.html).

> 4. What does implements means

It means it *follows* the types [present in the interface](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/interfaces.html).

> 5. What is a static and why it is assigned to the class name

What is static: It is a type of member present [on classes](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html).

Why it is assigned to the class name: It is not. `: AddItemsToShoppingBag` is a return [type annotation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html), *not an assignment*.